# ObservableCollection don't modify view

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I have strange WPF ObservableCollection behavior. By unclear reason when collection modified and there is another condition in getter-method in some property of my class, it does't modify View. Although CollectionChanged event was invoked! 
Without condition in getter method collection works good.

Too complicated and long-winded to explain here what I do in my work project. Therefore I make small simplify project and emulate same behavior. This project show you problem better then thousand words.

To see the problem - launch project as it is, looks how it works. It is really simple, 2 radiobuttons, datagrid and nothing else. Then go to the MainWindowViewModel, GridItems-property, uncomment commented code and launch project again. See the difference. When collection modify, get-method of GridItems-property dont't invoke (I check it with debugger). How not invoked method can make affect on something??? I don't have any idea on it. Help plz.

Project link:
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/443850/ObservableCollection-zip.html

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<GridItem>  _totalStorage;

        private ObservableCollection<GridItem> _gridItems;
        public ObservableCollection<GridItem> GridItems
        {
            get
            {
                //if (_gridItems.Count == 0)
                //{
                //    return _totalStorage;
                //}
                return _gridItems;
            }
            set
            {
                _gridItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("GridItems");
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _totalStorage = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>();
            _gridItems = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>();

            GridItemsInit();
            _gridItems.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Collection change event handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void CollectionChanged(object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void GridItemsInit()
        {
            _totalStorage.Add(new GridItem
            {
                Name = "Igor",
                LastName = "Balachtin",
                FilerField = FileStatusEnum.All
            });

            _totalStorage.Add(new GridItem
            {
                Name = "Misha",
                LastName = "Ivanov",
                FilerField = FileStatusEnum.All
            });

            _totalStorage.Add(new GridItem
            {
                Name = "Ahmed",
                LastName = "Magamed",
                FilerField = FileStatusEnum.All
            });

            _totalStorage.Add(new GridItem
            {
                Name = "abrek",
                LastName = "cheburek",
                FilerField = FileStatusEnum.All
            });

            _totalStorage.Add(new GridItem
            {
                Name = "Irka",
                LastName = "Dirka",
                FilerField = FileStatusEnum.All
            });
        }

        private void RefreshGridSource(string statusParam)
        {
            _gridItems.Clear();

            //Если нажали на баттон new
            if (statusParam.Equals(FileStatusEnum.All.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (var item in _totalStorage)
                {
                    _gridItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

            //Если нажали на archived
            else if (statusParam.Equals(FileStatusEnum.Filtered.ToString()))
            {
                foreach (var item in _totalStorage.Where(g => g.FilerField == FileStatusEnum.Filtered))
                {
                    _gridItems.Add(item);
                }    
            }
        }


        private RelayCommand<object> _radioCommand;

        public RelayCommand<object> RadioCommand
        {
            get { return _radioCommand ?? (_radioCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(HandlerFileRadio)); }
        }

        private void HandlerFileRadio(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return;

            var statusParam = obj.ToString();

            RefreshGridSource(statusParam);
        }

    }


Look at this sample.
//if (_gridItems.Count == 0)
//{
//    return _totalStorage;
//}

Model:

 public enum FileStatusEnum
    {
        All = 0,
        Filtered
    }

    public class GridItem
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }

        public FileStatusEnum FilerField
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <RadioButton Margin="5" IsChecked="True" Command="{Binding RadioCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="All">All</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Margin="5" Command="{Binding RadioCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="Filtered">Filtered</RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

really better post all code here instead of link? :/

Comment: Could you post the ViewModel code here?

Comment: @monstr, most don't have the resources to download a zip and run through a prescribed series of steps.  It means that your question falls in to the 'too broad' category, and I'll flag it for you as such.  Please edit your question to bring focus on the specific fragments in your view model that are misbehaving.  Formatted source will be to your advantage in getting this quickly resolved.

Comment: You should probably just have the total collection and bind to a [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) on top of it that filters.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are changing record after that your property is not Notifying.so please Notify after changing the collection.

Add below line in RefreshGridSource method after collection changed .

RaisePropertyChanged("GridItems");

Comment: ObservableCollection automatically notify if it changing. It does't work anyway...

Comment: so if I have NO filtered records it doesn't work properly. Thx, but it no solution of problem)

Comment: Download from here http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/443864/ObservableCollection-rar.html

Comment: Checked. I got you mean. But as I told you, in common case your suggestion is no solution, because I can have NO filtered records in my project. And your variant will not work. You try to get round problem using special case, but I need a solution in common case.
I appreciate ur answers anyway

Comment: Hm, I see with RaisePropertyChanged("GridItems"); get-method GridItems invoke now and if I have no records by filter, condition in getter works and I have _totalStorage as Source of my Grid. I.e. all list and visually grid has no changes. It is logically at least. So why ObservableCollection without invoke RaisePropertyChanged("GridItems") dont notify WPF about collection was changed? Was full and became emplty. And why it is happens only if I have that condition in getter??

Answer (score 0):

Your `GridItems` property can return either `_totalStorage` or `_gridItems` depending upon a condition; `_totalStorage` and `_gridSettings` are two **different** instances of `ObservableCollection`. Initially, when `_gridItems` has no items,  your `GridItems` property returns `_totalStorage` to WPF, and WPF listens on this instance for any CollectionChanged events.

In your `RefreshGridSource` method you are updating `_gridItems` (a differnt instance from `_totalStorage`), which WPF has no knowledge of.

But, when you rasie property changed for `GridItems` property from `RefreshGridSource` method WPF will re-read the property `GridItems` - this time, WPF gets `_gridItems` collection and it works as you expected.

Hope, I have explained well enough.

Comment: I fill so stupid... Lets go step by step plz. Why when I call
**_gridItems.Clear();** _gridItems dont tell to WPF update the grid-content? because **_gridItems** is ObservableCollection and must notify WPF about any changing on it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, WPF doesn't know about your `_gridItems` yet as WPF has got `_totalStorage` when it read `GridItems` property. Try `GridItems.Clear()` it will clear the grid, because `GridItems` will point to `_totalStorage` when `_gridItems.Count = 0`.

Comment: I got it. WPF stores first ObservableCollection which appeals. and assotiate GridItems with it. I'm very surprised. Great thx!